# Result Login in Encode Jwt

Tags: java, android

I'm confused how to do it, I managed to login to my Android login. But I want to take an ID member to use the CRUD, I save the result to the SharedPreferences. I want to take the username field and to create a data member. Furthermore, if I save the Result access in SharedPreffernces, what should I do? when I try to Create, complete the data member by using the Header and I put it in Retrofit 2, the results are Token Null object preferences

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "reason": "OK",
    "success": true,
    "message": null,
    "result": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiJ9.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.TEfYrLgKxPMmE4uqlnNcuEelWA4wxZHw6D5B1aM5xkU"
}
```

RetrofitClient.java

```
private static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl){
    TokenAuthenticator interceptor = new TokenAuthenticator();
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();

    if (retrofit == null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }
   return retrofit;
}
```

TokenAuthenticator.java

```
public class TokenAuthenticator implements Interceptor {

    SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager;


    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

        Request originalRequest = chain.request();

        Request newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization ", sharedPrefManager.getSPToken())
                .build();

        return chain.proceed(newRequest);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not initialized `sharedPrefManager` in TokenAuthenticator so you have to inialize it.

so you have to update your classes like below.

**RetrofitClient.java**

```
private static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(Context context,String baseUrl){
    TokenAuthenticator interceptor = new TokenAuthenticator(context);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();

    if (retrofit == null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }
   return retrofit;
}
```

**TokenAuthenticator.java**

```
public class TokenAuthenticator implements Interceptor {

    SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager;
   public TokenAuthenticator(Context context){
    sharedPrefManager=new SharedPrefManager(context);
   }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

        Request originalRequest = chain.request();

        Request newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization ", sharedPrefManager.getSPToken())
                .build();

        return chain.proceed(newRequest);

    }
}
```

Comment: `error: method getClient in class RetrofitClient cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,String
found: String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`

Comment: Error this message @Rajasekaran M

Comment: You have to update `public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl)` at RetrofitClient.java